# variable in function executed by invoke-command not visible

Tags: function, powershell, variables, scope, invoke-command

Can someone please help me get the below code to work?

```
$ab = "1"
function test {
$script:ab = "c"

}

invoke-command -ComputerName localhost ${function:test}
$ab
```

After running the above function by invoke-command I want to see value "c" for $ab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Note: `${function:test}` is an unusual instance of PowerShell's *namespace notation* and is equivalent to

`(Get-Item function:test).ScriptBlock`; i.e., it references the *body* of function `test`, as a *script block*.</sup>

When you use the `-ComputerName` parameter, `Invoke-Command` uses *remoting* to execute the specified script block - even if the target computer is the *same* machine (`localhost` or `.`).

*Remotely* executed code runs in a different process and has no access to the caller's variables.

Therefore:

- If *local* execution is the goal, simply *omit* the `-ComputerName` argument; then again, in that case you could simply run `. ${function:test}` or even just `test`:

  ```
  $ab = "1"
  function test { $script:ab = "c" }
  test  # shorter equivalent of: Invoke-Command ${function:test}
  ```
- For *remote* execution, *output* the desired new value from the remotely executed script block and assign it to `$ab` in the caller's scope:

  ```
  $ab = "1"
  function test { "c" } # Note: "c" by itself implicitly *outputs* (returns) "c"
  $ab = Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost ${function:test}
  ```